# Filtering for minimum values in multiple columns in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

sorry in advance if this answer isn't formatted well, I'm quite new to R and the SO community, I'd welcome constructive criticism.  I have a data frame that looks like this and am trying to filter it so it only contains the minimum 'Cars' and 'Houses' for each person.

```
my_data = data.frame("Name" = c("Dora", "Dora", "John", "John", "Marie", "Marie"), 
"Cars" = c(2, 3, NA, NA, 4, 1), 
"Houses" = c(NA, NA, 4, 3, 2, NA))
#Name   Cars   Houses
#1  Dora    2     NA
#2  Dora    3     NA
#3  John   NA      4
#4  John   NA      3
#5 Marie    4     2
#6 Marie    1     NA
```

I want to end up with something like this (especially note the Marie row has changed, but it's ok if that's split on 2 separate rows as well):

```
#Name   Cars   Houses
#Dora    2     NA
#John   NA     3
#Marie   1     2
```

OR like this:

```
#Name   Cars   Houses
#Dora    2     NA
#John   NA      3
#Marie   NA     2
#Marie    1     NA
```

Based on other answers, I've tried

```
my_data %>%
group_by(Name) %>%
filter(Cars == min(Cars))
#Name   Cars    Houses
#Dora   2       NA
#Marie  1       NA
```

but this results in the John rows being dropped before I can filter the minimum Houses. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to approach this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `summarise` to get the minimum of each column for each name:

```
my_data = data.frame("Name" = c("Dora", "Dora", "John", "John", "Marie", "Marie"), 
"Cars" = c(2, 3, NA, NA, 4, 1), 
"Houses" = c(NA, NA, 4, 3, 2, NA))

library(dplyr)
my_data %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  summarise(Cars = min(Cars, na.rm = TRUE),
            Houses = min(Houses, na.rm = TRUE))

`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Name   Cars Houses
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Dora      2    Inf
2 John    Inf      3
3 Marie     1      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do in base R:

```
df <- data.frame("Name" = c("Dora", "Dora", "John", "John", "Marie", "Marie"), 
                     "Cars" = c(2, 3, NA, NA, 4, 1), 
                     "Houses" = c(NA, NA, 4, 3, 2, NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

aggregate(df, list(df$Name), FUN = function(x) min(x, na.rm = TRUE))[,-1]
```

**Output**

```
   Name Cars Houses
1  Dora    2     Inf
2  John   Inf      3
3 Marie    1       2
```